# Where is the bazel release schedule posted?

Tags: release, bazel

I've tried looking on the site, but cannot find where the release schedule is.  I'm eagerly awaiting a feature that should be in the next release and don't want to miss it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The release tracking bugs are on GitHub, [tagged with `release`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20sort%3Aupdated-desc%20label%3Arelease). The next release (as of time of writing) is [tracked in this issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/5057).